# why does baking in Rigacar not work?

Tags: baking

all the widgets of the rigacar addon work perfectly when operated manually but the baking doesn't work at all. When I bake the steering I see no keyframes. but when I bake the rotation I can see keyframes but no rotation.  I hope somebody has some expirience with that. Thanks in advance. I've already tried other Blender versions but nothing helped so far

Comment: I've been facing the same issue using the addon version 7.1 on Blender 3.4. No keyframes are added when I bake. If anyone has a solution, please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just found out what my mistake was. I added the follow path as object constraint instead of a bone constraint